# Python TypeError: Object of type 'bytes' is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json

I would like to open and parse a JSON file, but I keep getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Object of type 'bytes' is not JSON serializable
```

Here is my code,

```py
class FileStore(object):
    def __init__(self, filePath, data = None):
        self.filePath = filePath
        self.data = data

    def store_json(self):
        with open(self.filePath, 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(self.data, outfile) # this is where the error occurs
```

Could please help me fix this issue?

Comment: What is `self.data`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
json.dump(self.data.decode(), outfile)
```

If your data is valid but only `Bytes` this will fix your problem.

Comment: thank you , I try, It appears different problems " list" object has no attribute 'decode'

Comment: Can you post sample of your data ?

Comment: Below is sample of my data. It is text document and my problem is text classification

Comment: " Mạo hiểm rừng Đa Mi Cuộc hành quân khám phá thác sương mù Ẩn mình trong cánh rừng Đa Mi (Hàm Thuận Bắc, Bình Thuận) bạt ngàn là hồ thủy điện Đa Mi đẹp như một nàng công chúa, ngọn thác sương mù hùng vĩ, cao ngất, uốn lượn như con rồng bạc khổng lồ...
Xuyên rừng vào thác sương mù "